# Azure Worker Role multithread queue processing

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have an azure Cloud service with classic configuration WebRole + Worker role.
The Worker takes messages from a queue, process it than delete it once at a time.

My code is like this:

```
public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Worker is running");
            try
            {
                this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.runCompleteEvent.Set();
            }
    }

public override bool OnStart()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
            bool result = base.OnStart();
            Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerAnalytics has been started");
            return result;
        }



private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var queue = ....//omitted info for brevity
            CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = null;

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                 try
                    {
                        retrievedMessage = await queue.GetMessageAsync();
                        if (retrievedMessage != null)
                        {
                            await ProcessMessage(retrievedMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Now this works perfectly but the CPU is very low, at 3%, it process only one element at a time (about 1 sec each), but the queue have about 1000 new elements per second and it is not enough.

**How can process more queue messages at a time using all the CPU power the machine has and without complicating too much this code?**

**Also what the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is for?**

I searched for hours for an effective multithreaded solution for Worker Roles but is all WebJobs now or old frameworks that complicate things.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try run multiple taks of `RunAsync()`.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token));
tasks.Add(this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token));
tasks.Add(this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work! 
How many tasks do you recommend to create? The azure machine is the dual core  one with 3GB RAM
The queue is very fast populated, like 1000 new records/sec, I`m afraid that I`ll need a lot of instances.

Comment: Well try to increase task count gradually and find right number of tasks. If you start seeing high CPU or performance degradation upgrade to bigger VM or run multiple instances of worker role

Comment: @pauliusnrk Where do I need to write this code ? instead of this line " this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();" ?

Comment: I got my answer, but now I have another question:

@pauliusnrk There is any way to allocate new task in run time ?
because i don't want to use 15-20 Tasks all the time just when the reach to certain threshold...there is a way to accomplish that ?

Comment: If you want to start/stop new tasks based on your workload you can start separate task task which time to time starts/stops tasks based on your workload

Comment: But the right way (I guess) would be to run one processing task synchronously, use smaller VM and setup azure cloud service auto scale on Azure portal based on queue size